# Mask raster with shapefile, error in colnames

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4

In the `R Raster package`, when I load a `netCDF` file into a `raster` and attempt to `mask` or `crop` the raster with a `shapefile`, I am getting the error:

```
"*Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = names(object)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions*"
```

Here is example code

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

nc <- brick("in.netcdf.nc", varname = "diff", values=TRUE )
crs(nc) <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
everShp <- shapefile("EVERareas")

nc.sub <- mask(nc, everShp)
```

Plotting shows both `nc` and `everShp` are 2D and spatially overlap. Thanks for any suggestions with this error.

Comment: Perhaps something in interfering with the `mask` function; have you tried `raster::mask (nc, everShp)`

Comment: Geo-sp, good suggestion, but no luck. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

if I replace

```
nc <- brick("in.netcdf.nc", varname = "diff", values=TRUE )
```

with

```
nc <- raster("in.netcdf.nc", varname = "diff", values=TRUE )
```

the mask and crop commands work as expected.